# Concurrent findAndModify queries succeed in updating the same document

Tags: java, mongodb

I have a task worker written in Java and using a MongoDB 3.4 replica set that runs many threads each doing essentially this.

- Run task
- Signal that task is complete by updating a document for that task in MongoDB
- Run a query to see if all the tasks in this set of tasks are done

  - If so, continue to next stage of processing
  - Otherwise, do nothing

As you may be able to see, there is a race condition here; multiple tasks can all finish at about the same time and think that they are the last task to complete. I want to use MongoDB to make sure only one of those tasks is allowed to start the next stage of processing.

I have the following code that is meant to ensure that only one of those tasks can continue (I'm using Jongo to interface with MongoDB).

```
Chipset modified = chipsets
  .findAndModify("{_id: #, status: {$ne: #}}", new Object[] { chipset.getId(), Chipset.Status.Queued })
  .with("{$set: {status: #}}", new Object[] { Chipset.Status.Queued })
  .returnNew().as(Chipset.class);

if (modified != null)
    runNextProcessingStep();
```

Pretty simple here; I'm just using findAndModify to change the status of the Chipset (set of tasks) to Queued. The one that successfully makes the change gets to execute runNextProcessingStep().

Or that's how I think it should work. In reality, several tasks, even ones that finish 2 seconds apart, are somehow getting back a non-null `modified`. As I understand it MongoDB should be locking the document when running findAndModify so that a non-null document can be returned no more than once.

I've read [Linearizable Reads via findAndModify](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.4/tutorial/perform-findAndModify-linearizable-reads/) and have implemented everything said in there. I've set the connection write concern to Majority and the read concern to Linearizable. I've created a unique composite index on _id and status. Still nothing. Perhaps I have misunderstood how findAndModify actually behaves? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I am facing same issue. Did you found any solution for this ?

Answer (score 1):

Well, this is embarrassing but in the interest of being a good internet citizen I'll update this with what happened. There was another thread that was changing statuses out from under me. I had convinced myself this couldn't be the case but, well, concurrency can be a real pain sometimes. findAndModify works exactly how I thought it should.